# Passport.js local strategy gives 401 error when trying to authenticate

Tags: mongodb, express, passport.js, http-status-code-401

The authentication process gives 401 bad request. Though the new user is saved to db with hashed password I noticed is saved to MongoDB Atlas. I'm using the local strategy. If I try "local-signup" for the register t I reach the secret route, but for the login route I still get the 401 bad request. 
Or can there be an authenticaiton issue with mongodb atlas trying to access the credentials??

```
app.post("/register", function (req, res, next) {
var newUser = new User({
username: req.body.username
});
User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function (err, user, info) {
 console.log(user);
 if (err) {
 return res.render("register");
} else {

// go to the next middleware
next();
 }
res.status(401).send(info);

});
}, passport.authenticate('local', { 
    successRedirect: '/secret',
    failureRedirect: '/login' 
})); 

app.post(
"/login",
passport.authenticate("local", {
successRedirect: "/secret",
failureRedirect: "/login"
}),
function (request, response) {}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. my misstake

passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate));

shold be

passport.use(new localStrategy(User.authenticate()));